# How to connect flutter with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, flutter-packages

*I have a website build with Nuxt JS and MongoDB.*

I want to create a mobile app with flutter and I don't know how to connect flutter with MongoDB.

**Give me some code examples.**

## Here is the solution! ([Click here](https://360techexplorer.com/connect-flutter-to-mongodb/))

Actually, I publish a blog about it feel free to check the solution!

1. Works with MongoDB and also **MongoDB Atlas**
2. Beginners guide

Comment: It's very interesting the fact that someone simply censor every single comment posted in your blog, that even slightly suggests that your "solution" of connecting your app directly to the DB is not a good idea, to say the least. I posted two comments a few minutes ago and both were rejected. I honestly don't find a reason to have a Blog which allows comments,... and at the same time censor and remove all the respectful comments that suggest another possible path forward. I don't think that encourages a healthy constructive criticism or even a conversation. Good luck then! Peace.

Comment: @ReinierGarcia, many blogs do not allow comments without manual check due to spam comments. your comment will be published :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Import flutter library **mongo_dart** and connect to the database. 
**[mongo_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/mongo_dart)** Server-side driver library for MongoDB implemented in pure Dart.

I hope the below code snippet helps !!

```
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart' show Db, DbCollection;
class DBConnection {

  static DBConnection _instance;

  final String _host = "DATABASE SERVER";
  final String _port = "DATABASE PORT";
  final String _dbName = "DATABASE NAME";
  Db _db;

  static getInstance(){
    if(_instance == null) {
      _instance = DBConnection();
    }
    return _instance;
  }

  Future<Db> getConnection() async{
    if (_db == null){
      try {
        _db = Db(_getConnectionString());
        await _db.open();
      } catch(e){
        print(e);
      }
    }
    return _db;
  }

  _getConnectionString(){
    return "mongodb://$_host:$_port/$_dbName";
  }

  closeConnection() {
    _db.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: what about atlas?

Comment: If someone makes an web-based flutter app, `mongo_dart` does not support it because of `dart:io`. Check it before using.

Comment: It is absolutely irrational to connect your front end client or mobile app directly to your DB, without using a Server which exposes the necessary API end points. Your API is the only one that should be connected directly to your DB. Otherwise every single user that unpacks your app's code, will have full access to all the API keys, AWS S3 secret keys, and every single Env variable with all the login data to your DB, etc, etc, etc. Will have absolute access to everything. This is suicidal.

Answer (score 13):

Answer by Sandeep Krishna is correct but if you already have a Nodejs backend then expose REST API and connect with Flutter using http, dio or other similar packages. As connecting frontend directly to database is bad. Its just a advice.

Comment: If i use nodejs backend as rest api then its bad for performence or not?

Comment: No it should not be bad for performance. You not doing heavy business logic in frontend, you just show a loader till data comes from backend. I advice you read first answer in this quora question: [Why do we need a back-end in web development? Can't the front-end directly send requests to the database?](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-need-a-back-end-in-web-development-Cant-the-front-end-directly-send-requests-to-the-database)

Comment: Which front-end framework or library i use to get best performance. (Ignore react)

Comment: Every framework for library is good if you know how use it, You can get good performance if you know how to use it, what are its limitation and how it works. It's not a direct answer like go and use this it will be better and everything out there and recommending a good framework needs a long discussion. If you need a answer now then go with anything you like it.