# why it is not good to connect to MongoDB without an API?

Tags: mongodb, flutter, mongo-dart

I want to use mongo atlas in my flutter project and currently, I am using the [mongo_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/mongo_dart) package and I am able to add documents directly from my app.

```
var db = await Db.create("mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.cwdcc.mongodb.net/<database>?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
await db.open();

var coll = db.collection('Users');
```

Recently I saw someone saying that I need to create API and it is not good to use MongoDB like this. Can you explain Why is that I need to create an API?

Comment: maybe try checkout something like [mongoose/browser](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/browser.html) for this purpose

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect flutter with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59924840/how-to-connect-flutter-with-mongodb)

Comment: @molaga I can't use it in flutter. It's only for the web

Comment: @NtshemboHlongwane I can connect to the database and add documents without creating an API but I want to know why it is not good to connect to MongoDB without an API?

Comment: You want to know what? You have a bit of typo there please fix so I can clearly understand

Comment: @NtshemboHlongwane sorry I edited the comment please check again.

Comment: Then I guess even your question needs a bit of editing, cause what you saying is different from question

Comment: I hope that answers your question why it's  not safe using an non-authenticated based connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based what you saying here i.e  `why it is not good to connect to MongoDB without an API?`

So I am to believe I stand to be corrected:

- So mongoDB atlas before even connecting to it you have to authenticate yourself
- Mongo will give you a connection string like this below:

`mongodb+srv://username:<password>@clustername.eoxer.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

- So it is much safer when then connection is an authenticated connection which mongoDB supports for the languages that they specified for their driver that they have
- So with flutter if you look at this solution given here:[How to connect flutter with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59924840/how-to-connect-flutter-with-mongodb) it seems like it is not an authenticated connection which makes it less secure

Comment: So you are saying it is totally fine to proceed further without creating an API in my case?

Comment: No I am answering why its not safe using the a non-authentication based connection, as for should you continue with this route personally I would said no reason being it's not safer approach of securing your data. I would thus advise if you do not know any language that mongo supports to use their driver I would say use firebase that is secure

Comment: I am afraid it might get expensive when it has a lot of data? Will it be a good choice for social media app?

Comment: Then if this a project that you then want to ship in to production and not just a play project then I would advise you learn how to use one of the mongo drivers supported by mongo. You have ```NodeJS, Python, Ruby, C, C++, C# / .Net``` and many more you just have to go mongoDB site and see then choose whatever that you prefer and start learning it

Comment: Is there any other database that will be better for social media that works with flutter?

Comment: Firebase is the only database that I could suggested right now check out their docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup  I hope my answer was what you want and solves your queries in mind :D

Comment: If you go with cloud firestore for a social media, there are hell lot of drawbacks. Complex queries are a headeche and the most important part searching. For searching anything like user names, you have to depend upon Algolia / ES which gets expensive over time.

Comment: @Ntshembo Hlongwane it is quite unclear what you mean with "non-authentication based connection". If it is no authenticated, Atlas doesn't let you in.

Comment: Hello, I know I am a bit late to this question, but I have a question? In mongo_dart Documentation, it says that you can add tsl=true or ssl=true and secure the connection in that way. I need the .watch() functionality implemented because I want to listen for realtime changes. I have tried using it with my Flask API and Socket.io, but I really don't understand how it works. What would your recommendation be @ Ntshembo Hlongwane?