# Cant connect to MongoDB on android device

Tags: mongodb, flutter

```
db = await Db.create("mongodb://10.0.2.2:27017/bestchat");
```

I have mongoDB on my pc. if I try connect to mongo on emulator it works fine.

```
db = await Db.create("mongodb://192.168.1.33:27017/bestchat");
```

But on real device I use wifi network local ip like 192.168.1.33 and it not work.
What the problem?

Comment: This may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59924840/how-to-connect-flutter-with-mongodb  
and did you added permission for internet  in manifest file ?

Comment: @HardikMehta I added this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` right now but it not work

Comment: also I get time out exception `ConnectionException (MongoDB ConnectionException: Could not connect to 192.168.1.33:27017
- SocketException: Connection timed out (OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110), address = 192.168.1.33, port = 33068)`

Comment: if you are in same network then you can try  mongodb://10.0.2.2:27017/bestchat  this way also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the reason is win firewall. I add rule for mongo and it works